# How to convert String to Long in Kotlin?

Tags: kotlin, string-parsing

So, due to lack of methods like `Long.valueOf(String s)` I am stuck.

How to convert `String` to `Long` in Kotlin?

Answer (score 234, accepted):

***1. `string.toLong()`***

> Parses the string as a [Long] number and returns the result.
>
> @throws NumberFormatException if the string is not a valid
> representation of a number.

***2. `string.toLongOrNull()`***

> Parses the string as a [Long] number and returns the result or `null`
> if the string is not a valid representation of a number.

***3. `string.toLong(10)`***

> Parses the string as a [Long] number and returns the result.
>
> @throws NumberFormatException if the string is not a valid
> representation of a number.
> @throws IllegalArgumentException when
> [radix] is not a valid radix for string to number conversion.

```
public inline fun String.toLong(radix: Int): Long = java.lang.Long.parseLong(this, checkRadix(radix))
```

***4. `string.toLongOrNull(10)`***

> Parses the string as a [Long] number and returns the result or `null`
> if the string is not a valid representation of a number.
>
> @throws IllegalArgumentException when [radix] is not a valid radix for string
> to number conversion.

```
public fun String.toLongOrNull(radix: Int): Long? {...}
```

***5.  `java.lang.Long.valueOf(string)`***

```
public static Long valueOf(String s) throws NumberFormatException
```

Answer (score 112):

`String` has a corresponding extension method:

```
"10".toLong()
```

Comment: Names have changed in Kotlin, you don't need to worry about where or why, just know in Kotlin that all `String` have an extension function `toLong()` as well as `toInt()` and others.  You can use these.  Maybe @ilya can update this answer to current Kotlin (remove `jet.String` reference.)

Comment: Just a heads up, if you're iterating a string of digits, they will be chars and [char].toInt() will give you the ascii representation.

Answer (score 62):

Extension methods are available for `String`s to parse them into other primitive types. Examples below:

- [`"true".toBoolean()`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.text/kotlin.-string/to-boolean.html)
- [`"10.0".toFloat()`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.text/kotlin.-string/to-float.html)
- [`"10.0".toDouble()`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.text/kotlin.-string/to-double.html)
- [`"10".toByte()`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.text/kotlin.-string/to-byte.html)
- [`"10".toShort()`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.text/kotlin.-string/to-short.html)
- [`"10".toInt()`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.text/kotlin.-string/to-int.html)
- [`"10".toLong()`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.text/kotlin.-string/to-long.html)

Comment: `str.toLongOrNull()` and other similarly named methods are also useful if you can't guarantee that the input will be formatted correctly. With this you can do stuff like `str.toLongOrNull()?.let { doSomethingWith(it) } ?: println("Please input a number")`

Answer (score 11):

*Note: Answers mentioning `jet.String` are outdated.  Here is current Kotlin (1.0):*

Any `String` in Kotlin already has an extension function you can call `toLong()`.  Nothing special is needed, just use it.

All [extension functions for `String`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin/-string/index.html#extension-functions) are documented.  You can find others for standard lib in the [api reference](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin/index.html)

Answer (score 9):

Actually, 90% of the time you also need to check the 'long' is valid, so you need:

```
"10".toLongOrNull()
```

There is an 'orNull' equivalent for each 'toLong' of the basic types, and these allow for managing invalid cases with keeping with the Kotlin? idiom.

Comment: Agreed. Most of the time .toLongOrNull() is what you need.

Answer (score 7):

It's interesting. Code like this:

```
val num = java.lang.Long.valueOf("2");
println(num);
println(num is kotlin.Long);
```

makes this output:

```
2
true
```

I guess, Kotlin makes conversion from `java.lang.Long` and long primitive to `kotlin.Long` automatically in this case. So, it's solution, but I would be happy to see tool without java.lang package usage.

Answer (score 6):

In Kotlin, to convert a `String` to `Long` (that represents a 64-bit signed integer) is simple.

You can use any of the following examples:

```
val number1: Long = "789".toLong()
println(number1)                                   // 789

val number2: Long? = "404".toLongOrNull()
println("number = $number2")                       // number = 404

val number3: Long? = "Error404".toLongOrNull()    
println("number = $number3")                       // number = null

val number4: Long? = "111".toLongOrNull(2)         // binary
println("numberWithRadix(2) = $number4")           // numberWithRadix(2) = 7
```

With `toLongOrNull()` method, you can use `let { }` scope function after `?.` safe call operator.

Such a logic is good for executing a code block only with non-null values.

```
fun convertToLong(that: String) {
    that.toLongOrNull()?.let {
        println("Long value is $it")
    }
}
convertToLong("123")                               // Long value is 123
```

Answer (score 4):

One good old Java possibility what's not mentioned in the answers is [`java.lang.Long.decode(String)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Long.html#decode(java.lang.String)).

---

*Decimal Strings:*

Kotlin's [`String.toLong()`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.text/to-long.html) is equivalent to Java's [`Long.parseLong(String)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Long.html#parseLong(java.lang.String)):

> Parses the string argument as a **signed decimal long**. ... The
>   resulting long value is returned, exactly as if the argument and the
>   radix 10 were given as arguments to the `parseLong(java.lang.String, int)` method.

---

*Non-decimal Strings:*

Kotlin's [`String.toLong(radix: Int)`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.text/to-long.html) is equivalent to Java's [e`Long.parseLong(String, int)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Long.html#parseLong(java.lang.String,%20int)):

> Parses the string argument as a signed long in the radix specified by
>   the second argument. **The characters in the string must all be digits of the specified radix** ...

And here comes [`java.lang.Long.decode(String)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Long.html#decode(java.lang.String)) into the picture:

> Decodes a String into a Long. Accepts decimal, hexadecimal, and octal
>   numbers given by the following grammar: DecodableString:
>
> (Sign) DecimalNumeral | (Sign) 0x HexDigits | (Sign) 0X HexDigits | (Sign) # HexDigits | (Sign) 0 OctalDigits
>
> Sign: - | +

That means that `decode` can parse Strings like `"0x412"`, where other methods will result in a `NumberFormatException`.

```
val kotlin_toLong010 = "010".toLong() // 10 as parsed as decimal
val kotlin_toLong10 = "10".toLong() // 10 as parsed as decimal
val java_parseLong010 = java.lang.Long.parseLong("010") // 10 as parsed as decimal
val java_parseLong10 = java.lang.Long.parseLong("10") // 10 as parsed as decimal

val kotlin_toLong010Radix = "010".toLong(8) // 8 as "octal" parsing is forced
val kotlin_toLong10Radix = "10".toLong(8) // 8 as "octal" parsing is forced
val java_parseLong010Radix = java.lang.Long.parseLong("010", 8) // 8 as "octal" parsing is forced
val java_parseLong10Radix = java.lang.Long.parseLong("10", 8) // 8 as "octal" parsing is forced

val java_decode010 = java.lang.Long.decode("010") // 8 as 0 means "octal"
val java_decode10 = java.lang.Long.decode("10") // 10 as parsed as decimal
```

Answer (score 1):

```
string.toLong()
```

where `string` is your variable.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want to handle `NumberFormatException` while parsing

```
 var someLongValue=string.toLongOrNull() ?: 0
```

Answer (score 1):

Actually, there are several ways:

Given:

```
var numberString : String = "numberString" 
// number is the Long value of numberString (if any)
var defaultValue : Long    = defaultValue
```

Then we have:

```
+—————————————————————————————————————————————+——————————+———————————————————————+
| numberString is a valid number ?            |  true    | false                 |
+—————————————————————————————————————————————+——————————+———————————————————————+
| numberString.toLong()                       |  number  | NumberFormatException |
+—————————————————————————————————————————————+——————————+———————————————————————+
| numberString.toLongOrNull()                 |  number  | null                  |
+—————————————————————————————————————————————+——————————+———————————————————————+
| numberString.toLongOrNull() ?: defaultValue |  number  | defaultValue          |
+—————————————————————————————————————————————+——————————+———————————————————————+
```

Comment: how can you have defaultValue =  Long : defaultValue Where would numberString get used in your example/ I think it ought to be defaultValue = Long : numberString?

Answer (score 0):

Here are several ways to do this:

```kotlin
// Throws exception if number has bad form
val result1 = "5678".toLong()
```

```kotlin
// Will be null if number has bad form
val result2 = "5678".toLongOrNull()
```

```kotlin
// Will be the given default if number has bad form
val result3 = "5678"
    .toLongOrNull()
    ?: -1L // The default
```

```kotlin
// Will be return of the run block if number has bad form
val result4 = "5678"
    .toIntOrNull()
    ?: run {
        // ...
        // return a Long
    }
```

```kotlin
// Ignores any none-digit character in the string
val result5 = "56abc78"
    .filter { it.isDigit() }
    .joinToString(separator="")
    .toLongOrNull()
```