# how to convert rgb color to hex color - kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin, type-conversion

This is what I do

```
val color = String.format("0XFF%02x%02x%02x", r, g, b)
```

this returns me a string "0XFFhexcode" I want to convert it to long, to store it and then use it as a color

```
color.toLong()
```

I have the following error

```
java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: 0XFFhexcode
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19519468/how-to-convert-string-to-long-in-kotlin

Comment: You're probably wanting `.toLong(16)` so it converts from a hexadecimal value to a `Long` value. You need to get rid of the leading `0X` to do that, though.

Comment: that works, but what I want is to store the value of a color.

Answer (score 1):

This code might help you:

```
Integer.toHexString(Color.rgb(r, g, b))
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it simply like the following:

```kotlin
val rgb =  Color.rgb(red, green, blue)
val hex = String.format("#%06X", 0xFFFFFF and rgb)
```