# how to use a string representation of a Long to declare a Long variable?

Tags: kotlin

I want to use the string representation of a Long to create a Long of this value

```
val strLong:String = "0xFF007A45"
```

And I want a Long with this value

```
val LongIWant:Long = 0xFF007A45
```

I tried toLong(), as Long and many other way, but none of them works

Is it possible ?

Regards

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to convert String to Long in Kotlin?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19519468/how-to-convert-string-to-long-in-kotlin)

Comment: Use `.toLong(16)` since you are wanting to convert it from hexidecimal. Leave off the "0x" part.

Answer (score 3):

```kotlin
val strLong: String = "0xFF007A45"
val longYouWant: Long = strLong.substringAfter("0x").toLong(radix = 16)
```